# Maya calendar does not synchronise with the Google account

Tags: release-freya, calendar

I'm using Freya with the latest updates.

When I try to synchronise my Google calendar with the built-in Freya calendar nothing happens.

I put the same name of my Google calendar in the Freya calendar, marked it as a default calendar and repeated the whole process multiple times to be sure that the password was correct.

What could be the problem, and is there any way to get some log to see what is happening when the calendar wants to connect to Google's server?

Comment: Unfortunately the link mentioned above does not tell anything about using Google Calendar with third party clients. So could someone please elaborate on the procedure?

Comment: Basically, you have to create a new password for every third party app you want to use. You can do that in your google account settings. It is a bit confusing but it works.

Comment: The same question... how to do this?

Comment: I am struggling with this as well. I am a returning elementray OS Freya user. Previously I just used to input my Google user name and password. allocate a name to the calendar and it used to import all my Google Calendar Information. Now, it does nothing. I even launched it using the terminal to see if some error log is generated, and nothing at all. I do make use of Google Apps for Work, Could this be the reason maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To synchronize your account on Google Calendar, you must configure it to accept third party applications. You can find more information at

[Google Calendar Support](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648)